# Yii2 ActiveForm TextField Number Max

Tags: yii2, active-form

I have fields like below

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone')
->textInput(['type' => 'number', 'maxlength' => 13])
->label('Phone') 
?>
```

why the `'maxlength'` is not work? and how to make it work?

thank you before

Comment: why are you using `type=number` for your input field any reason for that?

Comment: added an answer for you see if that helps you out

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam done sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work because you are using `type=>number` for your input field, you have to change it to `type=>text`.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone')
->textInput(['type' => 'text', 'maxlength' => 13])
->label('Phone') 
?>
```

Looking at your input it seems like you are doing it because you do not want the user to enter any other thing than numbers for the `Phone` field, `Yii2` provides you a very nice way to accomplish this i.e [**`yii\widgets\MaskedInput`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-maskedinput.html), you can format your input using the `mask` option to tell it how many digits to allow and in which sequence see the demos [**`HERE`**](http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/)

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
    'mask' => '999-999-9999',
]) ?>
```

apart from the solutions above, you can also have the option of validating this inside your model by using the custom validation option.

Your rule for phone inside your model should look like

```
[['phone'],'PhoneLimit']


public function PhoneLimit($attribute)
{
    if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{13}$/', $this->$attribute)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Please provide digits only no more than 13.');
    }
}
```

Comment: sure @IHUB take your time

Answer (score 1):

try for  type number -> 'type'=>'number', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 999